# parsing some values from string in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, string, parsing, extract

What's the best way in nodeJS to parse to following string to extract values described below?

```
client 111.222.333.44#59699: query: jadssdffsdnisa.website.com IN A -ED (81.11.11.175)
```

Current code:

```
//parsing
var c_ip = data.split("client ")[1].split("#")[0] 
var sdomain  = data.split("query:")[1].split(".")[0]  

console.log("c_ip: " + c_ip + '\n');    
console.log("sdomain: " + sdomain + '\n');
```

Results in:

```
c_ip: 130.225.244.66

sdomain:  paul
```

Comment: What assumptions can be made towards the length of c_ip and the structure of the query?

Comment: The c_ip will be always a IPv4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very depends on how your input string arrives but assuming that it has always that same format you could do something like this

```js
var task = "client 111.222.333.44#59699: query: jadssdffsdnisa.website.com IN A -ED (81.11.11.175)"

var c_ip = task.split("client ")[1].split("#")[0]
var sdomain  = task.split("query: ")[1].split(".")[0] 

console.log("c_ip:", c_ip)
console.log("sdomain:", sdomain)
```

further, if it varies more you could use regex. @jens-habegger has a good example

Comment: It won't varietes that much. Using your code there seems to be some whitespaces before the subdomain aren't they? I've edited first post.

Comment: This is probably faster than my answer using regex.

Comment: @peke_peke indeed. `query: ` needed an additional space at the end. it works now. The space that still remains is based on the `console.log()` function

Answer (score 0):

Use basic regex:

```
var string = "client 111.222.333.44#59699: query: jadssdffsdnisa.website.com IN A -ED (81.11.11.175)"

var c_ip_reg = /client\s(.*)#/;
var c_ip = string.match(c_ip_reg);

var sdomain_ref = /query:\s(.*?)\/;
var sdomain = string.match(sdomain_ref);
```

I'm aware this can be shortened into a multi-group match, but for the sake of readability I tried to be as verbose as possible.

.